# HTML/CSS Navbar out of order

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'm attempting to create a navbar with two dropdown menus and after lots of fiddling with the dropdown menu I've got it sorta working. But it's made the rest of the items out of order.

https://jsfiddle.net/o5pcs1y7/

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}

.header h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #2c3840;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c3840;
}

.header img {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #2c3840;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 41px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.nav a {
  font-family: Arial;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6d4b4f;
}

.projects {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.projects-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.projects:hover .projects-content {
  display: block;
}

.services {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.services:hover .services-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>


<title>Werribee Roadworthy Centre</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />



<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Werribee Roadworthy Centre</h1>
      <img src="car.png">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <div class="services">
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <div class="services-content">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="projects">
        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        <div class="projects-content">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="photos.html">Photo Gallery</a>
      <a href="conact.html">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
    <div class="section">

    </div>
    <div class="aside">

    </div>







  </div>
</body>
```

This is the code. The ordering of the navbar is correct in the HTML just not in the finished product. Also don't mind the broken dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parent `.nav` could have a child of `div` or either `a`, you didn't float the `div` to left like you float `a` and that what was making the mess:

you just have to add:

```
.nav > div {
  float: left;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}

.header h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #2c3840;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c3840;
}

.header img {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #2c3840;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 41px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.nav a {
  font-family: Arial;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.nav > div {
  float: left;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6d4b4f;
}

.projects {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.projects-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.projects:hover .projects-content {
  display: block;
}

.services {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.services:hover .services-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>


<title>Werribee Roadworthy Centre</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />



<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Werribee Roadworthy Centre</h1>
      <img src="car.png">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <div class="services">
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        <div class="services-content">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="projects">
        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        <div class="projects-content">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="photos.html">Photo Gallery</a>
      <a href="conact.html">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
    <div class="section">

    </div>
    <div class="aside">

    </div>







  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)